# gitlab signup users without email confirmation

Tags: gitlab

I want to setup a gitlab instance for internal use. Since the instance can only be reached over a local network I haven't setup the email setup. Unfortunately gitlab still wants to sent new users confirmation emails with a temporary password, but they never receive this email.

Is there a way to configure gitlab so that it doesn't send these confirmation mails? I already tried to set `email_enabled: false` in `gitlab.yml` but it didn't work.

Update:

It should work without me having to interfere manually in the signup process.

Comment: Go into the `users` table in `mysql` and put a value on `confirmed_at`?

Comment: It should be possible without me having to to something for them to sign up. I know it is possible to confirm them from the admin interface.

Comment: What GitLab version are you running? You might get a better answer on their [official forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/) - this question seemed offtopic for stackoverflow and *may* get closed.

Comment: I'm running version 7.9.4. Thanks I will try to official forums.

Answer (score 59):

Admin can confirm user manually!

1. Login gitlab with admin account and create a new user (Mini), ignore password.
2. Admin area ---> users ---> edit Mini user ---> set password.
3. User Mini can login gitlab.

Comment: how to get there (admin area) ?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi On the top of right corner it is a wrench logo.

Comment: yeah,, i just figured it out :|

Comment: This solution doesn't work if there's an LDAP connection letting them in. On first login (with their LDAP username/password) it requires them to provide an email address.

Answer (score 0):

I think GitLab takes security seriously and from what I have seen so far, it looks like either your users need to confirm their accounts or an admin has to confirm manually.